# In bootstrap table how to change default button icon using jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Example the data-show-export is an attribute of bootstrap table api which will give only a fixed icon how to change that using jQuery

data-show-export ="true"

Answer (score 0):

you can use .attr

```
$('table').attr('data-show-export', true)
```

Comment: how to change the icon to some other icon i wish

Comment: i think the icon in bootstrap is using fontawesome right? you can change it by change the class attribute of the icon tag

Comment: yes i am changing using fa class but can you show the code i am new to jQuery and confused as hell , thanx a ton for the help

Comment: let's say you have this edit icon <i class="nav-icon fas fa-edit" id="x"></i>
if you want to change the iconto lock icon, the code is $('#x').removeClass('fa-edit') then $('#x').addClass('fa-lock')

Comment: thats great but i am unaware of the original button class as this button comes from bootstrap table API attributes and there is no option in the documentation to edit the default see https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/table-options/

Comment: you have to search that button/icon using browser inspect, then you can define the selector for it

Comment: example this code doesnt work  $('table').attr('data-show-export',true).addClass('fa-lock')

Comment: the selector isn't 'table' because it is a button, not a table

Comment: Okay i got that but now how to edit the attribute given that    $('table').attr('data-show-export',true).removeClass('fa.fa-download') is not working

Comment: yess i dont have the button id since it is a table attribute

Comment: like i said, inspect the button (hover it, right click mouse, select inspect). then you can get the selector for it

Comment: ohk i got that but this code is not working                                                                   $('data-show-export').removeClass('fa-download')
$('data-show-export').addClass('fa-user')

Comment: because it aint that. if you've gotten the selector, then $(selector).removeClass('fa-download'); $(selector).addClass('fa-user')

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to this
get a style tag and change the internal css
For example .fa-search-minus:before{content: "\f0b0" ;}